# JPA+Hibernate MySql database schema changes does not reflect

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my spring web service I am accessing a my sql database with JPA+Hibernate. When I changed my database schema in the database, those changes are not reflecting from my web service.

In more detail I have added a new column formcategoryid to applicationforms table and it is added to JPA annotated class as a field. Now when I execute the query

```
 SELECT x.formid,x.formcategoryid,x.formname FROM com.business.objects.ApplicationForms AS x WHERE x.adminroleid LIKE '3'
```

It gives the exception,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: formcategoryid of: com.business.objects.ApplicationForms
```

Any idea on this?

---

UPDATE

My ApplicationForms class is like

```
    package com.business.objects;

    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "applicationforms")
    public class ApplicationForms {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private int formid;
        private int formcategoryid;
        private int adminroleid;
        private String formname;
        .
        .


        public int getFormid() {
            return formid;
        }

        public void setFormid(int formid) {
            this.formid = formid;
        }



        public int getFormcategoryid() {
            return formcategoryid;
        }

        public void setFormcategoryid(int formcategoryid) {
            this.formcategoryid = formcategoryid;
        }

        public int getAdminroleid() {
        return adminroleid;
        }

        public void setAdminroleid(int adminroleid) {
        this.adminroleid = adminroleid;
        }

        public String getFormname() {
        return formname;
        }

        public void setFormname(String formname) {
        this.formname = formname;
        }

}
```

Comment: provide us your code on com.business.objects.ApplicationForms

Comment: code looks ok. you have tried clean build your project? how if you select all field in the table and see your new field value after..

Comment: Are entities and web service in the same project? It seems like your entities classes are not been updated in your web service project

Comment: @ Daniel: Still it gives exception,

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'applicatio0_.description' in 'field list',
Where description is an already removed field from schema

Comment: @angel_navarro: No they are in two projects. Web service project depends on the other one. Can you please tell me how to update them?

Comment: Thanks @angel_navarro: I found it. The jar file has not updated when rebuilding the web service.

Comment: @Diluu, it depends how are you running your web service project. If you are using an IDE, this dependency can be set directly in your web service project. If not, your entities's project finally will generate a JAR file. This jar file must be in the web service project's classpath.